# Customers being redirected to login page when logged in and loading the checkout page

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, customer-session

I am using Magento 2.2.2 and have an odd problem. Below is an itemised route to the error.

1. Existing customer logs in
2. Customer adds a product to the basket
3. Customer clicks the go to checkout button
4. Checkout page loads
5. Checkout page redirects customer to login page

Prior to the redirect, an ajax request (usually the shipping estimation) returns a 401 error message.

This only affects customers who have been to the site before. Another curiosity is that when incognito mode is used. The error does not occur.

There are no exceptions reported, or anything obvious in the system.log

Comment: You might have disable checkout for guest user from the configuration..

Comment: Nope, guest checkout has been enabled

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem, magento 2.2.2

- Existing Customer adds a product to the basket
- Customer clicks the go to checkout button
- Checkout page loads
- Existing customer logs in
- Checkout page redirects customer to login page

Guest checkout is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue on our site from the basket page.
It appears to occur when selecting the "Checkout" button before all sections of the page have completed.  in my case, the totals had not fully been displayed